# rzc rewritecss exited with code -532462766 error while running an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC project in VS 2022

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

While creating an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC project, pressing run throws this error - this is the output log:

> Build started at 6:25 PM...
>
> Build started: Project: AnotherTest, Configuration: Debug Any CPU
>
> F:\VisualStudio\AnotherTest\AnotherTest\AnotherTest.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.3.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1' instead of the project target framework 'net6.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
>
> Unhandled exception. System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly'C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk\7.0.202\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor\tools\rzc.dll'.
> Format of the executable (.exe) or library (.dll) is invalid.
> File name: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk\7.0.202\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor\tools\rzc.dll'
>
> C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\dotnet\sdk\7.0.202\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.ScopedCss.targets(170,3): error : rzc rewritecss exited with code -532462766.
> Done building project "AnotherTest.csproj" -- FAILED.

I have tried the following steps:

- Reinstalled VS 2022
- Added all the individual components for ASP.NET Core
- Installed and uninstalled .NET Core 6.25 SDK

Comment: " This package may not be fully compatible with your project.'"  these libraries are not compatible with asp.net core. you should just remove them from the project as they can not be used.